# Laravel POST failing - MethodNotAllowedHttpException (405) - even with POST Route and CSRF defined

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form with the method **post** set and the **csrf_field()** included:

```
<form method="post">
{{ csrf_field() }}

...
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-space btn-primary">Save and finish</button>
</form>
```

Within my Routes, I have set everything up appropriately:

```
Route::get('/assess/{room_name}/{subject_selected}/{unit_selected}/{outcome_selected}', 'AssessmentHandler@step_6_assess');
Route::post('/assess//{room_name}/{subject_selected}/{unit_selected}/{outcome_selected}', 'AssessmentHandler@step_6_save');
```

The functions within the Controller are defined and everything should be working fine.

However, when I submit the form I am getting this error message:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \
>   MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message

I have not seen this message before and am not sure where this is being triggered from in my particular instance. All of the search results I've read about this specific error talk about changing from GET to POST or ensuring CSRF protection is in place, but that isn't my issue here.

Using Dev tools, it is showing a 405 error (Method Not Allowed).

Any idea what might be happening here?

Comment: What is the exact path of the Url that it's posting to, in the Dev tools?

Comment: Just found the error. The double // in the post route

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try replacing `{{ csrf_field() }}` with `@csrf`.
You also have 2 slashes in the post url: `Route::post('/assess//{room_name}`

Make sure you are redirecting to the correct page.

Maybe you could show us the code in your controller.

Is your controller really `AssessmentHandler` and not `AssesmentHandlerController`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It was the double // that caused the issue.